# Close alert / pop-up window automatically VBA

Tags: vba, excel, popup

Please try the code below, what is doing is downloading some data from the surface of a webpage, but I need it to work automatically and the proble appears when opening the Excel, the pop-up window. Is there any way to get rid of it automatically pressing ENABLE?

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
(ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub DownPDF()
' This macro downloads the pdf file from webpage
' Need to download MSXML2 and MSHTML parsers and install
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:10"), "DownPDF"
Dim sUrl As String
Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim hAnchor As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement
Dim Ret As Long
Dim sPath As String
Dim i As Long

sPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\ee28118\Desktop\Ordine\"
sUrl = "http://cetatenie.just.ro/wp-content/uploads/"

'Get the directory listing
Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
xHttp.Open "GET", sUrl
xHttp.send

'Wait for the page to load
Do Until xHttp.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'Put the page in an HTML document
Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText

'Loop through the hyperlinks on the directory listing
For i = 0 To hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a").Length - 1
    Set hAnchor = hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a").Item(i)

    'test the pathname to see if it matches your pattern
    If hAnchor.pathname Like "Ordin-*.2013.pdf" Then
        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, sUrl & hAnchor.pathname, sPath & hAnchor.pathname, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            Debug.Print sUrl & hAnchor.pathname & " downloaded to " & sPath
        Else
            Debug.Print sUrl & hAnchor.pathname & " not downloaded"
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: if that's for Enable macros, you would have to set the macro security level of Excel wither veruy low (so it doesn't care) or very high (so it won't even give you the option)

Comment: where is the excel msgbox or alert - I don't see any alert

Comment: It is nothing withthe code, but a security as you noted below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting your Excel Security level very high or low on the desktop then Exel won't protect you from malicious code that might run when you open a workbook (but a good anti-virus software will do it anyway!)

- Very High means it won't ask you
- Low means it won't ask you.

HTH

Philip

Comment: so when are you getting the error? I ran your code and there is no workbook opened so no 'enable' dialog

Comment: so this isn't a problem with your code, but when you open the Excel workbook running the above code, you get the standard security message?

Comment: exactly, the standard "careful" msg...can I egt rid of it?

Comment: You can either create a security certificate for the VBA Project or set Security to Low.

Comment: I did set security to low and it doesn't  work, but I have no clue how to create certificates yet...

Comment: have a look at [About digital signatures](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-digital-signatures-HP001039792.aspx) and [Using Digital Certificates in Excel VBA](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s240/digital_certificates_for_macros.htm)

Comment: you need to read the links I give above and also read [HOWTO: Signing your own macros with SelfCert.exe](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/selfcert.htm) and [OFFICE: Show Trust by Adding a digital signature](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/show-trust-by-adding-a-digital-signature-HA010342008.aspx) and [MSDN KB: Using SelfCert to Create a Digital Certificate for VBA Projects](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/217221)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it asks you to enable Macros is because a macro can actually harm to your PC. It is a security issue and you cannot override that feature automatically through VBA.

A person has to manually go to Excel:
"Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Enable all macros(not recommended; potentially dangerous code can run)"

Comment: what is trust center? do you mean Tools->Optoins-> Security?

Comment: oh.. you are using 2007 or less? Yes in security.. you need to set it to Low and you will be ok

Comment: alternatively add a Digital Signature to the VBA project (if allowed by company policies etc)